# Unable to connect to Redis : nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:6379

Tags: caching, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cli, redis-server

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {

    RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .disableCachingNullValues();
      Set<String> cacheNames = new HashSet<>(){};
      cacheNames.add("cacheA");
      cacheNames.add("cacheA");

   return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
                    .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).intitalCacheNames(cacbuild();

}
```

I am using the above code to setup redis connection and running redis-server.exe locally. But i am not able to establish connection while doing rest call. I tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1. server seems to be up as i receive pong when i type ping in cli. Can someone help what could be the issue